# Django views error in importing custom python files

Tags: python, django

I am trying to import `main1.py` file in `views.py` of my django app.
But unable to import it.
Moreover location of my main file and sub-dependent file also lies at the `view.py` folder location.

I have tried with following options

1 `import main`
with this error is : `No module found with name main`

2 `from .app_name import main`
using this error is : `import * only allowed at module level`

folder structure is

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `from .main1 import *`? However I'd advise you against `import *` and import explicitly the functions/classes you need, e.g. `from .main1 import my_function`

Answer (score 2):

The name of the file is `main1.py`, but you are trying to import `main.py`.

Try:

```
from app_name import main1   # Absolute import.
from . import main1          # Explicit relative import.
import main1                 # Implicit relative import. Won't work in Python3.
```